# How to get CPU usage or disk usage of application using Windows API from C++?

Tags: c++, windows, cpu, disk

How to proceed to get CPU usage or disk usage of application using API in C++???

I want to get the highest CPU usage or disk usage among the application running on windows.
I have tried to find out API but there is no direct API for that. Can anyone please let me know how to proceed for this in C++.

Answer (score 2):

You look at the Process category performance counters to get per process CPU/Memory/IO or at respective categories (Processor, Memory, Physical/Logical Disk) counters for overall system performance. The values can be accessed via [dedicated APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373083(VS.85).aspx)  or from [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392397(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 already has this built-in, as part of the Resource Monitor (realmon.exe). If you want to find this in code, you can either use the Perf Counter API or create a Realtime ETW consumer against the NT kernel provider.